# How to restore files from time machine backup (on Apple Time Capsule) of a different computer?

Tags: finder, backup, time-machine, restore, time-capsule

I need to find some files located in a time machine backup of an old computer. It's a backup located on an Apple Time Capsule.

As it's used as my router, I've tried going to Finder, then clicking on the Time Capsule under locations, entering the password and connecting. Then there's a folder called 'Data'. Within it there is the backup for the old computer in .dmg file format. From other things I've read, when it's a backup on an external drive there should just be a folder you can click in to, to look at files. That's not the case here when it's on a time capsule. If you 'show package contents' of the .dmg there's nothing usable or viewable, just lots of exec files.

I've also tried go to time machine in the menu bar and press alt, 'browse other backup disks' but that doesn't seem to work and just shows me a today finder window for my finder.

It would be great if someone knows what to do here. Thanks

Comment: As far as I've been able to tell, the "browse other backup disks" option is just broken, and doesn't work anymore. (I assume it once did.) I'd also love to know if there's any working way to do this.